# npm start (with express.js) yields UUID

Tags: node.js, express

Something very odd is happening with npm start using express.js (4.0). When I run npm start, the application starts for about 1 second, then yields a UUID. Any thoughts?

```
npm start

> dashboard@0.0.0 start /Users/nparsons/Code/px/dashboard
> node ./bin/www

ccb2f844-e6e7-4c66-bcb1-78f4ac406e08
```

The UUID changes every time that I run npm start.

The contents of ./bin/www are

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('dashboard:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: check what `npm start` in `package.json` does

Comment: @SwarajGiri it calls node ./bin/www

Comment: Then that uuid is a result of what ever `./bin/www` executes, ending with a `console.log(); process.exit()` . Search for it

Comment: Nick we need to see some of your code to be able to help you debug this, giving us your console output is like giving us the task of finding a needle in a haystack.

Comment: `www` is file or one folder?

Comment: @Svenskunganka Updated code to include contents of ./bin/www

Comment: Maybe related to `start /Users/nparsons/Code/px/dashboard`?

Comment: @zangw it is standard express.js start code. it was working fine prior to an npm rebuild. ended up removing node_modules and running npm install... now this is happening.

Comment: It could be anything in you var app = require('../app'); check for app/index.js file what it is requiring. It could be any module you have required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being that that UUID NPM library was in dev dependencies. Not sure how it made it's way there, but it did. Moving it to production dependencies, and clearing / re-installing npm dependencies did the trick.